# Elegant way to check co-ordinates of a 2D NumPy array lie within a certain range

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

So let us say we have a 2D NumPy array (denoting co-ordinates) and I want to check whether all the co-ordinates lie within a certain range. What is the most Pythonic way to do this? For example:

```
a = np.array([[-1,2], [1,5], [6,7], [5,2], [3,4], [0, 0], [-1,-1]])

#ALL THE COORDINATES WITHIN x-> 0 to 4 AND y-> 0 to 4 SHOULD
 BE PUT IN b (x and y ranges might not be equal)

b = #DO SOME OPERATION
```

```
>>> b
>>> [[3,4],
    [0,0]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the range is the same for both directions, x, and y, just compare them and use `all`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[-1,2], [1,5], [6,7], [5,2], [3,4], [0, 0], [-1,-1]])
a[(a >= 0).all(axis=1) & (a <= 4).all(axis=1)]
# array([[3, 4],
#        [0, 0]])
```

If the ranges are not the same, you can also compare to an iterable of the same size as that axis (so two here):

```
mins = 0, 1   # x_min, y_min
maxs = 4, 10  # x_max, y_max

a[(a >= mins).all(axis=1) & (a <= maxs).all(axis=1)]
# array([[1, 5],
#        [3, 4]])
```

---

To see what is happening here, let's have a look at the intermediate steps:

The comparison gives a per-element result of the comparison, with the same shape as the original array:

```
a >= mins
# array([[False,  True],
#        [ True,  True],
#        [ True,  True],
#        [ True,  True],
#        [ True,  True],
#        [ True, False],
#        [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Using `nmpy.ndarray.all`, you get if all values are truthy or not, similarly to the built-in function `all`:

```
(a >= mins).all()
# False
```

With the `axis` argument, you can restrict this to only compare values along one (or multiple) axis of the array:

```
(a >= mins).all(axis=1)
# array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
(a >= mins).all(axis=0)
# array([False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Note that the output of this is the same shape as array, except that all dimnsions mentioned with `axis` have been contracted to a single `True`/`False`.

When indexing an array with a sequence of `True, False` values, it is cast to the right shape if possible. Since we index an array with shape `(7, 2)` with an  `(7,) = (7, 1)` index, the values are implicitly repeated along the second dimension, so these values are used to select rows of the original array.

Comment: Range might not be the same...I forgot to add it in the question

Comment: @DuttaA: Added a variant with differing ranges.

Comment: Nice looking code....i am a syntactical noob so can you explain what does the `all` and `axis` do? So i may improvise this solution to new peoblems

Comment: @DuttaA: Added some description.

Comment: Thanks..really appreciate the help.

Comment: @DuttaA: Because `&` is overloaded for `numpy` arrays to perform element-wise `and` comparisons, but `and` cannot be overloaded (it is not an operator per se).